# How can i read float as string

Tags: php, csv, phpspreadsheet

I want to read the csv file with phpspreadsheet as follows.

"999999.5999999" -> 999999.5999999

However it can only be read as follows.

"999999.5999999" -> 999999.6

When reading a csv file using phpspreadsheet, how can we read it as follows?

"999999.5999999" -> 999999.5999999

```
$csvReader = new CSVReader();
$spreadsheetCsv = $csvReader->load($folderName . $fileName);

$arrayData = $spreadsheetCsv->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

The code below should work you, it will first set the number format and once set you will get the data:

```php
$csvReader = new CSVReader();

// apply format for all cells
$spreadsheetCsv->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1:A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);

$arrayData = $spreadsheetCsv->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
```